Error in stacking ensemble in tensorflow
densenet = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/densenet169_model.keras")
vgg19 = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/VGG19_model .keras")
xception = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/xception_model.keras")
effnet = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/EfficientNetV2B2_model.keras")

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(128,128,3),name="input_layer")

densenet_output = densenet(inputs)
vgg19_output = vgg19(inputs)
xception_output = xception(inputs)
effnet_output = effnet(inputs)

concat = layers.Concatenate()([densenet_output,vgg19_output,xception_output,effnet_output])

outputs = layers.Dense(4,activation="softmax",name="output_layer")(concat)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs,outputs,name="concatenated-model")

model.summary()


The models I loaded were fine-tuned on a specific dataset. the same steps work when I load the pre-trained models from TensorFlow, but I'm encountering this error when working with my fine-tuned models.Please help me out

Check the outputs of your individual models, these seem to be lists containing the tensors instead of tensors itself.

yes,they are lists.I tried convertig them into tensors,but I'm getting error that I cant convert them since they are place holders.How can I resolve it

I would expect that you can use normal list indexing to select the tensors from the list.
